# how to remove admob banner view from my game through robovm?

Tags: in-app-purchase, libgdx, admob, robovm

This article shows how to add admob banner in your libgdx game through robovm.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx 
It actually did.But when I open my game,admob banner will appear at the top of the view and can't be removed.That is a problem because I plan to use IAP to remove ad in my game.I have tried a lot of functions and they could not solve the problem.
the functions include:

```
adview.setFrame(new CGRect(0, -bannerHeight, bannerWidth, bannerHeight));
    adview.close();
    adview.release();
    adview.dispose();
    adview.removeFromSuperview();
```

I have no idea now.can you help me?
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`adView.pause();` will pause serving of ads.

`adView.setVisible(View.GONE);` will hide the AdView.

`layout.removeView(adView);` will remove the AdView from your layout.

Comment: Your code appears to be Android not iOS, and you didn't mention in your question that you were looking for any platform specific advice.

Comment: he said robovm in his title... which is a bridge to iOS from Java. I'm also looking for this answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling:

```
adview.removeFromSuperview();
```

In case you need to add it back, just call:

```
iosApplication.getUIViewController().getView().addSubview(adview);
```

again (I do this because I hide the banner during the game and just show it on the WorldMap).